# "have might" or "might have"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, modal-verbs

Is the following sentence correct? To my knowledge, "might" should precede "have", but in the following sentence (from this [website](http://oldwestdailyreader.com/horse-breeds/)), it has used in reverse process. Please explain.

> These are most of the horse breeds one ***have might expected*** to encounter in the old west.

Is it fine to change the above sentence as

> These are most of the horse breeds one ***might have expected*** to encounter in the old west.

Comment: The second sentence is correct. The first sentence is definitely wrong.  ("might expected" doesn't work at all, though it is possible to use "have might" in a sentence that makes sense, e.g., "All of the horses I have might be expected to [something]".

Comment: That's not the only sentence that is wrong (even horrible). Just because some wrote some sentences on a website in English doesn't mean they are all grammatically and syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an error to me. You are right in that, it is ***might have*** and not 'have might'. The correct sentence will be as you have stated in the description:

> These are most of the horse breeds one might have expected to encounter in the old west.

**Might have** and **may have** are verbs that are used to state that something might have happened now or in the past. For example:

> They might have left now.

or,

> They may have left an hour ago.